# Is it possible to access an FTP server with MySQL commands?

Tags: mysql, ftp

I'm trying to accomplish a task that seems impossible since I've yet to find a thread with the same problem.

I want to access an FTP server via MySQL in order to execute a .sql file periodically. I'm familiar with the command for executing a local file:

```
mysql> \. C:/backup/MyArchive.sql
```

I tweaked my command a little to do what I want:

```
mysql> \. ftp:/administrator@192.168.102.200/backup/MyArchive.sql
```

As expected, result was "*failed to open file '~path', error: 22*"

To be precise, I'm not allowed to copy "MyArchive.sql" from the FTP server to my local machine (prof's instructions) otherwise I wouldn't need to crack my head looking for a workaround.

If what I want to do is downright impossible do tell me so that I can just chuck this problem back at my professor... ^^ Thanks

PS: `MyArchive.sql` is simply a file with some SQL syntax like:

```
CREATE TABlE History (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Country STRING, Inter INTEGER);
INSERT INTO "History" VALUES (Canada, 88);
```

Comment: do it in the shell then get into mysql and use it

Comment: Ye i did that before and it works, but now my professor doesn't want me to copy the file, I must execute it from where it is AKA the ftp server.

Comment: nope, this class is all about MySQL, so technically I'm suppose to use methods from MySQL itself and not rely on other ways, otherwise I would've just used ftp> get and voila ^^. Anyway it's not really that vital, it could just be that it's something that can't be done and my teacher is just wasting our time to 'test' us (happens).

Comment: well give him that answer below and test him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1) First install curlftpfs package. On Debian or Ubuntu it would simple as:

# apt-get install curlftpfs

2) Create/Mount ftp directory

# mkdir /mnt/my_ftp

next use curlftpfs to mount your remote ftp site. Suppose my access credentials are as follows:

username: ftp-user
password: ftp-pass
host/IP: my-ftp-location.local
the actual curlftpfs mount command would be:

# curlftpfs ftp-user:ftp-pass@my-ftp-location.local /mnt/my_ftp/

3) tweak your path in mysql to go against /mnt/my_ftp
```

Comment: Well it works, although it wasn't what he was waiting for... He'll be handing out the corrections soon, i'll update once i get it ^^ Thanks for your help, i really appreciate it :)